# how to download dynamic spacebar menu?

Tags: add-on

I have downloaded and installed Blender 2.78 several times, and noticed that the Dynamic Spacebar Menu missing and instead there is Dynamic Context Menu. Sometimes, in many tutorials Dynamic Spacebar menu is used, but I couldn't download it.

Answer (score 1):

The "Dynamic Context Menu" is the new name, probably with added functionality, of the "Dynamic Spacebar Menu".